# std::find across a set of shared_ptr

Tags: c++, find, containers

I'm sure I'm doing something stupid here, but I can't see it.  Why doesn't the following compile?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

// A class to play with.  Encapsulates a name.
class StringClass
{
public:
    StringClass(std::string const & name) : MyName(name) 
    {
    }

    std::string const & Name() const
    {
        return MyName;
    }

private:
    std::string MyName;
};

// The set of instances of "StringClass".

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<StringClass>> MyInstances;

// Function returns "true" if a class with the given name exists in the collection.
bool Exists(std::string const & name)
{
    auto i = std::find(MyInstances.begin(), MyInstances.end(), [&](std::shared_ptr<StringClass> const & instance) {
        return instance->Name() == name;
    });

    return i != MyInstances.end();
}
```

I've made a vector of shared_ptr to a class.  The class has a Name() property.  All I want to do is iterate the vector looking for an instance of the class with the given name.  However, it doesn't compile :(.

Errors are:

> 1>ClCompile: 1>  test.cpp 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual
>   studio 10.0\vc\include\algorithm(41): error C2679: binary '==' : no
>   operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const
>   `anonymous-namespace'::<lambda0>' (or there is no acceptable
>   conversion) 1>          could be 'built-in C++
>   operator==(std::_Bool_type, std::_Bool_type)' 1>          c:\program
>   files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\exception(470): or
>   'bool std::operator ==(const std::_Exception_ptr &,const
>   std::_Exception_ptr &)' 1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft
>   visual studio 10.0\vc\include\exception(475): or       'bool
>   std::operator ==(std::_Null_type,const std::_Exception_ptr &)' 1>
>
>   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   10.0\vc\include\exception(481): or       'bool std::operator ==(const std::_Exception_ptr &,std::_Null_type)' 1>          c:\program files
>   (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\system_error(408): or
>
>   'bool std::operator ==(const std::error_code &,const
>   std::error_condition &)' 1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft
>   visual studio 10.0\vc\include\system_error(416): or       'bool
>   std::operator ==(const std::error_condition &,const std::error_code
>   &)' 1>          while trying to match the argument list
>   '(std::tr1::shared_ptr<_Ty>, const`anonymous-namespace'::)'
>   1>          with 1>          [ 1>              _Ty=StringClass 1>
>   ] 1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   10.0\vc\include\algorithm(74) : see reference to function template instantiation '_InIt
>   std::_Find*,`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda0>>(_InIt,_InIt,const`
>   anonymous-namespace':: &)' being compiled 1>          with
>   1>          [ 1>              _InIt=std::tr1::shared_ptr
>   *, 1>              _Ty=StringClass 1>          ] 1>          c:\svn\trunk\test\test\test.cpp(55) : see reference to function
>   template instantiation '_InIt
>   std::find,`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda0>>(_InIt,_InIt,const
>   _Ty &)' being compiled 1>          with 1>          [ 1>              _InIt=std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::tr1::shared_ptr<StringClass>,std::allocator<std::tr1::shared_ptr<StringClass>>>>, 1>
>
>   _Myvec=std::_Vector_val<std::tr1::shared_ptr<StringClass>,std::allocator<std::tr1::shared_ptr<StringClass>>>,
>   1>              _Ty=`anonymous-namespace':: 1>          ] 1> 
>   stdafx.cpp 1>  Generating Code... 1> 1>Build FAILED. 1> 1>Time Elapsed
>   00:00:00.87
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: Could you format your error message in monospace please, as it's painful to read right now...

Comment: You need to implement some operators methinks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to use `find_if`, not `find`. `Find` searches for a value, `find_if` takes a predicate.

Comment: @Robinson your current code will try to match the entire lambda function to the shared pointers in your vector. using `find_if` will actually invoke the lambda as the predicate you intended.

Comment: Ah!  I'm having far too many "slaps forehead" moments on SO of late.